# Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option. Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6

Tags: android, kotlin, jvm, inline, bytecode

Have try the following solutions but still not working at all :

```
- added      
kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

on build.gradle/app

- Settings > Other Setting > Kotlin Compiler > Target JVM Version to "1.8"
- Clean & Rebuild Project
- Invalid cache and Restart
```

Any advice?

Thank you.